# How to make a light query for a many to many relationship in Google Apps Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How to make a light query for a many to many relationship?

Users has many Lists

the `ListUser` is the model that links them

Currently I'm doing like this but there are a lot of get queries to get all this data.

```
lists = []
for list in user.lists:
    lists.append(list.list)
```

Now I got this:

```
list_users = user.lists.fetch(1000)
# problem is here: "list.list" will retrive data from database, but I just want that list's key, how to do?
list_keys = [list.list for list in list_users]
lists = List.get_by_key_name(list_keys)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [get_value_for_datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass.html#Property_get_value_for_datastore).

```
list_keys = [ListUser.list.get_value_for_datastore(list_user)
              for list_user in list_users]
lists = db.get(list_keys)
```

If you have not already, you might want to take a look at some of the '[mastering the datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/datastore/overview.html)' articles.  Specifically the one on [modeling relationships](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html). Perhaps you can accomplish what you need using a list of List keys instead, maybe it will save you a query.

Comment: This can work too, right?
list_users = user.lists.fetch(1000);
list_keys = [list._list for list in list_users];
lists = List.get(list_keys);

Comment: Yes, that also works.  With the current implementation of ReferenceProperty the two methods are effectively identical.  However, get_value_for_datastore is publicly documented, so you code is less likely to be broken by any internal changes.

Comment: And is any way to only request the list's key? When I query for user.lists.fetch(1000) so it would be mych lighter

Comment: You could potentially make it 'lighter' by storing a list of db.Keys for each user.  That would allow you fetch a user then directly fetch their list of groups from the list of Keys.  It would also allow you to easily find all users who are in a particular group with an easy query.

Comment: And yes, I generally prefer get_value_for_datastore since it is a 'public' api function.

Comment: @Robert Kluin: thanks, but as each user can have a large number of lists, shared and each has metadata is better with the linkage model.